# Convert local element in global element declaration

Tags: xsd

I am looking to automate a method to replace local element declaration in global element declaration.

Like this:

```
<xs:schema>
  ...
  <xs:element name="aaa">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bbb">
           ....content bbb ...
        <xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="ccc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bbb">
           ....content bbb' ...
        <xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ...
 <xs:schema>
```

to

```
<xs:schema>
  ...
  <xs:element name="aaa">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="bbb"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="ccc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="bbb"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="bbb">
    <xs:complexType>
      .... Valide for bbb and bbb' ...
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ...
 <xs:schema>
```

Does anyone know a method or tool to achieve this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref5) to an existing global element, then you can define your element bbb such as it is valid for both bbb and bbb' cases:

```xml
<xs:schema>
  ...
  <xs:element name="aaa">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="bbb"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="ccc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="bbb"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="bbb">
    <xs:complexType>
      .... Valide for bbb and bbb' ...
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ...
 <xs:schema>
```

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my sample (I have just corrected it). I know that it is necessary to use ref attributes. My questioning is mostly on the existing methods to merge and "streamline" the bbb and bbb' contents inside a single content.

Comment: are bbb and bbb' significantly different ? You can use a choice inside bbb type; you can have bbb type as an abstract type and have 2 implementations of it; you can also use a substitutionGroup on bbb, where bbb' content can replace bbb.